# I need to make a Number Spelling Game program in python

Tags: python

The program will display random numbers on the screen and requests for the spelling of that number. It checks if the input is correct, then it displays another number. If the input is wrong, then it will send an error message and request another answer. It need to track the number of correct and wrong answers and display it at the end.

Here's the what I've done so far:

```
import random

numberList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
word = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"]
number = random.sample(numberList, 10)
trials = 3
correct = 0
wrong = 0
attempts = 10

print("HELLO, WELCOME TO THE WORD SPELLING GAME!\n")
print("SPELL AS MUCH NUMBER AS YOU CAN TO GET POINTS!")
print("----------------------------------------------\n")

for element in number:
    spell = str(input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':'))

    while attempts > 0:
        if element == numberList[0]:
            if spell.lower() == word[0]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[0]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 0:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[0]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[1]:
            if spell.lower() == word[1]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[1]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[1]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[2]:
            if spell.lower() == word[2]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[2]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[2]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[3]:
            if spell.lower() == word[3]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[3]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[3]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[4]:
            if spell.lower() == word[4]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[4]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[4]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[5]:
            if spell.lower() == word[5]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[5]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[5]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[6]:
            if spell.lower() == word[6]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[6]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[6]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[7]:
            if spell.lower() == word[7]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[7]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[7]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[8]:
            if spell.lower() == word[8]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[8]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[8]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
        elif element == numberList[9]:
            if spell.lower() == word[9]:
                correct = correct + 1
                attempts = attempts - 1
            elif spell.lower() != word[9]:
                trials = trials - 1
                print("Incorrect spelling. ", trials, " trials left.")
                if trials > 1:
                    spell = input('Spell ' + str(element) + ':')
                    if spell.lower() == word[9]:
                        correct = correct + 1
                        attempts = attempts - 1
                else:
                    print("Sorry! Number of trials exceeded.")
                    wrong = wrong + 1
                    trials = 3
                    break
    else:
        print("\n-----------------------------------------------")
        print("END OF GAME!\n")
        print("CORRECT SPELLING SCORE: ", str(correct), "\n")
        print("WRONG SPELLING SCORE: ", str(wrong))
```

Comment: You have 10 conditional blocks that are almost the same. Imagine if your spelling test was with 1 million numbers instead of 10. You wouldn't write 1 million conditional blocks, just as you shouldn't write 10. You need to write a routine that will generate the string for the correct answer. Your wrapping loop should call that routine once per number and compare it with user input. After that it's just keeping track of guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want.

I have changed your import at the top. I have also added some more variables at the top. I have replaced all your condition blocks with a regular function. You can see that if have used ".lower()" as this will stop it from being case sensitive.

```
from random import randint

numberList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
word = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
        "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"]
trials = 3
correct = 0
wrong = 0
attempts = 10
attemp_number = 0

print("HELLO, WELCOME TO THE WORD SPELLING GAME!\n")
print("SPELL AS MUCH NUMBER AS YOU CAN TO GET POINTS!")
print("----------------------------------------------\n")


def validate_user_input(random_number_to_spell):
    global wrong, correct, attemp_number
    result = False
    while result == False and attemp_number < attempts and wrong < trials:
        print("Please spell the number: ", random_number_to_spell)
        user_input = input()
        correct_spelling = word[random_number_to_spell-1]
        if user_input.lower() == correct_spelling.lower():
            print("You spelled ", random_number_to_spell, " correctly")
            correct = correct + 1
            result = True
            attemp_number = attemp_number + 1
        else:
            print("You did not spell", random_number_to_spell, "correctly")
            wrong = wrong + 1
            attemp_number = attemp_number + 1


while wrong < 3:
    if attemp_number < attempts:
        random_number_to_spell = randint(1, 10)
        validate_user_input(random_number_to_spell)
    else:
        break

print("You have ", correct, " correctly spelled numbers")
print("You have ", wrong, " wrong spelled numbers")
```

Comment: Thank a lot for the help! I'm just a beginner in Python so this is very eye-opening.